# Call API in another page in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I would like to put my calls to my API in a separate page and not in the template page of my app. So, I create a file "customersAPI.js" and I put this code :

```js
export function findAllCustomers () {
   axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers')
    .then((reponse)=>{
      console.log(reponse.data['hydra:member'])
     return reponse.data['hydra:member']

    }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

So I try to retrieve my data in my template page and put these data in data but It does not work because of the asynchronous thing of api call and because I don't know how to pass the data...
I do this in my template page :

```js
data() {
    return {
      customer: [],
    }
  },


mounted() {
    this.getAllCustomers();
  },
 getAllCustomers() {
this.customer = findAllCustomers();
}
```

I know it is not the good way to do this but I don't know how to do... So I need clarification about that. And, every time I go into the documentation, there are no examples with an API call outside of the part where there is the page template. Is it a good practice to want to put the api call apart? And in general calls to functions so that the code is not too long?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

In your case I advise you to try add async in mounted or in func.

```
 async mounted() {
    this.customers =  await this.findAllCustomers();
  },

------
 methods: {
   async getAllCustomers(){
      this.customer = await findAllCustomers(); 
   }
 }
```

But better practice to fetch information from store:

COMPONENT

```
<script>
import {mapActions} from 'vuex' 
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            customer: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.customer = this.fetchAll();//better to get via getters
    },
    methods() {
        ...mapActions('customers', ['fetchAll']),
        //OR 
        // fetchAllCustomers(){
        //     this.$store.dispath('customers/fetchAll')
        // }
    }
}
</script>
```

STORE

```
// async action that put all customers in store 
    const fetchAll =  async ({ commit }) => {
        commit(types.SET_ERROR, '')
        commit(types.TOGGLE_LOADING, true)
        try {
          const { data} = await customerAPI.findAll(namespace)
          commit(types.SET_ALLIDS, data['hydra:member'])
          commit(types.TOGGLE_LOADING, false)
          return data['hydra:member']
        } catch (error) {
          commit(types.TOGGLE_LOADING, false)
          commit(types.SET_ERROR, error)
        }
      },
```

API

```
// func that receive promise
export function findAll () {
   return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers')
}
```

Please read about vuex
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

Comment: Thanks. I am a beginner...so I don't understand the code in the "store" part of your response.. I tried with adding async getAllCustomers() ... in the methods part but it does not work. I don"t understand why I should to use the state for that. I just want to separate my code because it is tooooo lonnnnng ! Thks